# When using FLASHBACK TABLE TO RESTORE POINT, why do I get 'ORA-38780: Restore point ‘string’ does not exist.', even though the restore point exists?

Tags: oracle

If you start an Oracle XE database:

```
docker run --rm -d --name oracle -e ORACLE_PWD=oracle container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
```

And you connect as sysdba:

```
docker exec -ti oracle bash -c 'sqlplus / as sysdba'
```

And you enable `FLASHBACK`:

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
STARTUP MOUNT;
ALTER DATABASE ARCHIVELOG;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE = '10G';
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST = '/tmp' SCOPE=BOTH;
ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON;
CREATE USER c##test IDENTIFIED BY "test";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO c##test;
```

And you log in as `c##test`:

```
docker exec -it oracle sqlplus 'c##test/test'
```

And you execute:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A ( ID INT );
ALTER TABLE A ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
CREATE RESTORE POINT BASE;
FLASHBACK TABLE A TO RESTORE POINT BASE;
```

You will get:

```
SQL> CREATE RESTORE POINT BASE;

Restore point created.

SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE A TO RESTORE POINT BASE;
FLASHBACK TABLE A TO RESTORE POINT BASE
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-38780: Restore point 'BASE' does not exist.
```

Flashback itself works, when used with timestamp:

```
SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE A TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' minute);

Flashback complete.
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it? As far as I can see, I'm doing the same thing [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-RESTORE-POINT.html#GUID-AD0FB693-7C28-4908-A870-BA884B320575__GUID-EFFC40DA-8FA5-4784-BF83-5C2D3C7D7BD9). I suspect it has something to do with CDB/PDB but I don't understand it yet. As usual, the Oracle error message is not very specific :)

The goal is to create an Oracle database Docker image with base data for system testing, so that after each test the DB can be reverted to the restore point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an Oracle bug where common users cannot flashback tables. If you switch to a regular PDB user, your flashback command will work fine.

I think I see what you're trying to do here - you want to minimize the number of databases and the number of users you have to manage. Unfortunately, you went a bit too far by trying to use only the CDB and common users. The CDB and the common users are always going to be weird. If you want to replicate the traditional, simple, "one database and one user" paradigm, you need to do as much as possible inside a PDB instead of the CDB. Only directly use the container CDB when necessary.

Comment: I created a user in `XEPDB1` and (after waiting 5min after enabling row movement), it worked! Thank you very much